# Gazebo 5.4 premature release?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Today I got the following problem when launching Gazebo (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
[Err] [RTShaderSystem.cc:414] Unable to find shader lib. Shader generating will fail.[Err] [Server.cc:285] Could not open file[worlds/empty.world]
terminate called recursively
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3322, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver --verbose -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/jvgomez/.ros/log/7bf27612-df0f-11e6-a9b3-7824afa13789/gazebo-2.log].
```

After investigating a bit I saw that I have the following folders:

```
/usr/share/gazebo
/usr/share/gazebo-5.3
/usr/share/gazebo-5.4
```

The first two only have a `setup.sh` but the third one has `media` and `worlds` folder. After copying these to     `/usr/share/gazebo-5.3` everything was working again.

Investigating further, I saw that in `/usr/bin` there are ony 2 binaries : `gazebo` and `gazebo-5.3.0`. In fact, synaptic shows that `gazebo5-common` package has been updated to `5.4.0-1~trusty` while the others are still `5.3.0-1~trusty`.

Have been those packages released by error? Or for some reason my update is not complete?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15247/gazebo-5.4-premature-release?/) by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Javi:

Thanks for the report, the problem is in our repository. What happened was that the gazebo 5.4.0 i386 build finishes just fine but the gazebo 5.4.0 amd64 failed. All the architectures shared the gazebo-common package this is why you find a mixture of gazebo 5.4.0 for gazebo-common and 5.3.0 for the rest of them.

The buildfarm is building the gazebo5 amd64 packages again, the problem should be fixed in less than two hours.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2017-01-20**:
The problem should be now solved. Please comment if you see another problem. Thanks!

**Comment by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on 2017-01-23**:
@jose Luis Rivero Gazebo 5.4.0 up and running, thanks a lot!

**Comment by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on 2017-01-23**:
@Jose Luis Rivero Gazebo 5.4.0 up and running, thanks a lot!